# Python - Intranet Web Service

Tags: python, kerberos

About to embark on a Java project using Spring Security to create a Restful Web Service (JSON) that will use Kerberos authentication to authenticate users in Active Directory.

I'm not locked into using Java and am considering the use of Python to gain new skills and look at potential alternative platforms.

So far I have looked at Twisted and Web2Py but they don't seem to have support for Kerberos nor could I find information around implementing Kerberos support.

Does anyone know of frameworks supporting the above deployment or pointers to get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python Eve](http://python-eve.org/) is a restful api written in Python that uses mongo as its backend.

It provides a simple class that you can use to implement your own authentication which would allow you to use the [python kerberos module](http://python-notes.boredomandlaziness.org/en/latest/python_kerberos.html)

I use this setup but with ldap instead of kerb.

The underlying web framwork behind eve is [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: To be honest I had hoped for a few options but it seems to be something that isnt commonly done. Thanks to frodopwns, will take a closer look at Python Eve.

Comment: Eve is the only pre-built python restful api I know of.  You can easily roll a less sophisticated one on your own using Flask or Django.